# Message Box Answer Being Ignored?

Tags: vba, excel, messagebox

I have an ActiveX command box that is supposed to print a report. Users are given the option to print a compact version. If yes, the code is supposed to hide some rows and set a sheet to Portrait orientation. If no, the report is printed using the defaults of the sheets.

As of now, no matter what you click, the full report is printed using the defaults of the sheets, instead of the coded parameters. How can I fix this?

```
Private Sub SummarizedReport_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Answer As Integer

ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect


MsgBox "Would you like to Print a Compact Version of this Estimate?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Print Dialogue"

    If Answer = vbYes Then

        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Unprotect
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Rows("F:I").Hidden = True
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").PageSetup.Orientation = xlPortrait
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperLetter

Sheets("Cover Page").Visible = -1

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Cover Page", "SUMMARY")).Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

        Sheets("Cover Page").Visible = 2

    Sheets("SUMMARY").Rows("F:I").Hidden = False
    Sheets("SUMMARY").Protect


    Else

        Sheets("Cover Page").Visible = -1

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Cover Page", "SUMMARY")).Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

        Sheets("Cover Page").Visible = 2

    End If

ActiveWorkbook.Protect

Worksheets("Control").Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You get the respond by `Answer = MsgBox(...)`.

Comment: Where would I put that?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the two pieces tripping you up.
At the top during declarations.

```
Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult
```

When you go to query the user for an answer:

```
answer = MsgBox ("Would you like to Print a Compact Version of this Estimate?", vbYesNo, "Print Dialogue")
```

Then run your code based on

```
If answer = vbYes Then
'your code for yes
Else 'assumes it was no.
'your code for no
End if
```

Comment: correct!  That is what you get for looking at one screen and typing in another.

Comment: take @YowE3K's advice.  He is much better than I.

Comment: I guess I should point out that there was nothing particularly wrong with `Dim Answer As Integer` (all the enum values are below 7, so it would happily convert the `MsgBox` result to an integer), but using the correct enum type allows Intellisense to work better - i.e. when you start typing the line of code `If Answer = ` then it will prompt you with all the valid values to choose from.

Comment: @YowE3K Just to make sure that I have this correct; because I used it as an integer, I should have it checked as the numerical value of vbYes (6), instead of simply vbYes?

Comment: @TomStone No, `vbYes` is an enum value which has a value of 6.  So you can compare the enum value with the integer value quite happily, VBA will do a type conversion as required.  So `Answer = 6` will be the same as `Answer = vbYes`.  It's just that, if you declare `Answer` as a `VbMsgBoxResult` then Intellisense makes your work easier for you when you are typing your code - it will let you select the `vbYes` from a list rather than having to manually type it (as you undoubtedly had to do when you declared `Answer` as `Integer`).  And using the correct type helps prevent other coding mistakes.